# Create Widget that Passes Date to Query in Azure Databricks

Tags: sql, azure, parameters, widget, azure-databricks

I need to create a widget in Azure Databricks that allows me to pass a date to a query.

The MSSQL version of this code is (note I have simplified the problem greatly, this is part of larger query where I am attempting to avoid a self join):

```
DECLARE @MAXstartdate DATE = (SELECT MAX(startdate) FROM table
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE startdate = @MAXstartdate
```

I've tried:

```
SET mbr.MAX = (SELECT MAX(startdate) FROM table);

CREATE WIDGET mbr.MAX DEFAULT SELECT MAX(startdate) FROM table
```

However Azure turns an error on both of these.

Comment: I thought widgets were for UI stuff.  But in any case, why can't you just use `select .. from table where startdate=(select max(startdate) from othertable)`?

Comment: Could you please provide the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate the issue in my environment with some sample data:

```
create table sampletable(Id int , startdate Date)
insert into sampletable(id,startdate) values(1, '2023-04-04'),(2,'2023-04-23'),(3,'2023-04-12')
```

[image]

with your code:

```
DECLARE @MAXstartdate DATE = (SELECT MAX(startdate) FROM sampletable
SELECT *
FROM sampletable
WHERE startdate = @MAXstartdate
```

I got below error:

[image]

I resolved the issue by following code:

```
SELECT *FROM sampletable
WHERE startdate = (SELECT MAX(startdate) FROM sampletable)
```

[image]

I created a widget with the result of above query using below code:

```
CREATE WIDGET DROPDOWN maxdate DEFAULT "2023-04-23"  CHOICES SELECT  MAX(startdate) FROM sampletable ;
```

[image]

I was able to access the widget value using below code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sampletable
WHERE startdate = getArgument('maxdate')
```

[image]